# Swift 2.0 - Graph API - How to store received data ?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a function that use Graph API, that searches for places,

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/search", parameters: ["q":"coffee",
                        "type":"place", "fields":"id,name", "HTTPMethod":"GET"])
                    .startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
```

and this is a screenshot of my results:

[image]

I'm trying to fetch these information to my app... so far I found out these info are stored in **result["data"]** , but i do not know how to go deeper and get these id's and names..

if you have any thoughts, please share them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store result["data"] as array, after that you can check for the particular index for the dictionary containing the values

ex:

```
if let arrData = result["data"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {
  let name = arData[0]["name"]
  print("name \(name)")
}
```

if you are going to display it in tableview/collection view like structure you pass the array to rows and get dictionary at individual indexpath

Comment: im getting this error : Type 'AnyObject!!' has no subscript members, in this part:  " arrData[0]["name"],

Answer (score 0):

create an empty Dictionary first

```
var receivedIdAndNames = [Int:String]()

FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/search", parameters: ["q":"coffee",
                    "type":"place", "fields":"id,name", "HTTPMethod":"GET"])
                .startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
```

than, in the graph completion handler;

```
for (id,name) in result[data] as! Dictionary {

   receivedIdAndNames[id] = name } //end of for loop
```

lastly you can use receivedIdAndNames any place in your code you want.

Comment: I keep getting this error : Type 'AnyObject!!' has no subscript members, in this statement : "in result["data"] "

Comment: thanks Çağrı for your time, check the solution above